# What math do I need to know for MD5?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, algorithms, hash-function

This could fit into a lot of areas of SO but I feel like mathematics will know best.

What area of math is used for something like an MD5 or SHA algorithm?

Is there a mathematical equation/skeleton for something like it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

While I do not know what you mean by "mathematical equation/skeleton," to understand how MD5 is implemented, all you need to know is high school `algebra`, `bit vector algebra` (e.g., if A and B are two size $n$ bit vectors, what A XOR B, A AND B, etc. mean), plus the ability to read a simple computer program.  Look at the sample code in the English-language Wikipedia entry for MD5.

When people talk about these algorithms, they often use the language of `fields`, `vector spaces`, and the like, from undergraduate algebra.  They also use elementary `probability reasoning`.

Where prerequisites get hairier is for algorithms that use `primes`, `factoring`, etc., or, worse yet, `elliptic curves`, but things like MD5 are relatively simple.

Comment: I admit I don't know how to prove MD5 is hard to invert, isn't there a technical proof that it is not a bad cryptographic hash function and that inverting it would require solving a difficult problem (as the semi-prime factorization for RSA) ?

Comment: I do not know if anything can be proved in the way of reducing the inversion problem for MD5 to a known hard problem.  Such a thing is not mentioned in https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc6151, an overview of MD5's security.